# is it possible to populate a primary key of a table based on a column of another table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key

I have a table that contains a text-type column(for example graph path : 12 5 7 19 30 ..) and I want to split this text by space and put all of the output strings as a primary key in the other table.

Note that the strings found can be repeated so each time I will be adding a new primary key, I will check if it is already there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a simple INSERT ... SELECT statement:

```
insert into target_table (the_pk_column)
select u.key
from regexp_split_to_table('12 5 7 19 30', '\s+') as u(key)
on conflict (the_pk_column) do nothing;
```

or based on the column of the source table

```
insert into target_table (the_pk_column)
select u.key
from source_table st
   cross join regexp_split_to_table(st.graph_path, '\s+') as u(key)
where st.id = ... --<< whatever you want to select
on conflict (the_pk_column) do nothing;
```

Comment: Thank you. In terms of performance, how can I enhance the efficiency of this query ?